# Redmine - ruby process eating 100% memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, redmine

I have installed Redmine on cent-os.  I have configured it on Apache with Passenger .And It s been used by hardly 400 people. At the particular point of time ,Ruby Process eats to much of  memory. Almost 100% of the memory .

I am not able to see from where the leakage is going on in the ruby process. Just can see in the top ruby is reaching to 90% and some times more then 99%.

Is there any way to solve the issue. Any Deployment solution there or any way to check where is the process leakage in ruby code?
Here are some details of the version I am using on RVM

```
gem -v
1.8.24
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v
Rails 2.3.14
```

Comment: 100% of 256MB is not much, 100% of 4GB is. How much memory do you actually use? Please post at least an excerpt of a `ps aux`

Comment: 4 gb ram. 80gb harddisk .